# Generating all subsets of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion

First of all please don't mark it as duplicate I already have seen the other question but none of them clear my doubt.

I wrote a code to generate all the possible subsets for an array which looks like this, but unfortunately it returns an empty array:

```
def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
    def fun(subset,idx,nums, current):
        subset.append(current)
        while idx<len(nums):
            current.append(nums[idx])
            fun(subset, idx+1, nums, current)
            current.pop()
            idx+=1
    nums.sort()
    subset=[]
    fun(subset, 0, nums, [])
    return subset
```

lets say `nums=[1,2,3]`

The result I want : `[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]`

the result I get: `[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]`

Can anyone tell me where I possibly am going wrong?

Comment: look at `def powerset(..)` in https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes it returns as tuples what you want as lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your main issue is that you try to insert a reference to the list and not a `copy` of it, just insert a copy instead and your solution works as a charm:

```
def subsets( nums):
    def fun(subset,idx,nums, current):
        subset.append(current.copy())
        while idx<len(nums):
            current.append(nums[idx])
            fun(subset, idx+1, nums, current)
            current.pop()
            idx+=1
    nums.sort()
    subset=[]
    fun(subset, 0, nums, [])
    return subset
    
a = subsets([1,2,3])
print(a)
```

output:

```
[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @YossiLevi. Your tweak proved to be helpful !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(nums):
l=[]
for i in range(len(nums)):

    l.append(nums[i])
    print(l)
    if l==nums:
        f(nums[1:len(nums)])

f([1,2,3,4,5])
```

You can use func in func method.
For example nums=[1,2,3,4,5].
If our list (l) = nums then nums will be [2,3,4,5] and our code do the same thing to the end.(Sorry my english is not well.)